# systemd mount script problem

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I am trying to run a mount script using systemd. It did run but the mount point doesn't appear (`/with`). If I execute `/usr/local/sbin/utils-start.bash` manually, it works.

`/etc/systemd/system/test2d.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=test2d

[Service]
User=root
Type=oneshot
#Start script
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/utils-start.bash
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/local/sbin/utils-start.bash`

```
/bin/mount -v --make-rshared /
/bin/mount -v --bind /with /with
/bin/mount -v --make-rprivate /with
/bin/mount -v -t tmpfs with-global /with
```

`journalctl -xe` result:

```
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: test2d.service: Trying to enqueue job test2d.service/start/replace
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: test2d.service: Installed new job test2d.service/start as 15762
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: test2d.service: Enqueued job test2d.service/start as 15762
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=n/a object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=JobNew cookie=868731 reply_cookie=0 e
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: test2d.service: Job test2d.service/start finished, result=done
May 05 16:26:48 dev3 systemd[1]: Started Initializes the file system namespaces for /usr/bin/with.
-- Subject: Unit test2d.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit test2d.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had to run

```
systemctl enable test2d
```

else it wouldn't work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/708438)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh it sure looks like an answer to me

Comment: @Zanna I'll need to learn this first, I wanted to mark it as **Less descriptive** or something, My 6 hours of Review experience isn't something to brag about I guess

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh thank you very much for reviewing. Many people do not do it at all, and it's very important to the site :) of course it takes practice. Also, I am often wrong about stuff. You are not the only reviewer who recommended deletion of this. But I think this was the solution in OP's case.